# Trying to remove a sprite during intersection of the object and character in sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, ios7, int, sprite-kit, sknode

Good afternoon, using Xcode / Spritekit / OSX 10.9.1

I am set up 3 methods to call upon hearts in a tutorial I was trying to expand upon.
The hearts are displayed on the scene as follows:

```
-(SKSpriteNode*) healthContainer1 {

    SKSpriteNode *heart1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"heartfull"];
    heart1.name = @"healthContainer1";
    heart1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 25, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 30);

    return heart1;

    if (hitCount == 3) {

        [self removeFromParent];

    }

}

-(SKSpriteNode*) healthContainer2 {

    SKSpriteNode *heart2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"heartfull"];
    heart2.name = @"healthContainer2";
    heart2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 30);

    return heart2;

    if (hitCount == 2) {

        [self removeFromParent];
    }

}

-(SKSpriteNode*) healthContainer3 {

   SKSpriteNode *heart3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"heartfull"];
   heart3.name = @"healthContainer3";
   heart3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 75, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 30);

   return heart3;

   if (hitCount == 1) {

       [self removeFromParent];

   }

}
```

The heart containers are called in the `initWithSize:` method by

```
[self addChild:[self heartContainer1]];
[self addChild:[self heartContainer2]];
[self addChild:[self heartContainer3]];
```

My `hitCount` is an int set up in the header file and I use the following method along with the 2nd posted part of the update method to detect damage.  I am trying to get the `heartContainer` to remove itself when damage is done based on the `hitCount` int.

```
-(void) doDamage:(SKSpriteNode*)character {

    isDamaged = YES;

    hitCount ++;

}

if ( [character intersectsNode:node] && isDamaged == NO) {

    [self doDamage:character];
    NSLog(@"Intersection occured");

}
```

Sorry if it is excess code displayed on the multiple `heartContainer` methods, I was just thinking I could check the int in the `heartContainer` method itself then remove it if the condition was met.  I also tried putting the if statements in the `initWithSize:` method right after calling them and this did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things...

1) The following code will never be executed because it follows a `return` statement that is always executed:

```
if (hitCount == 1) {
    [self removeFromParent];
}
```

Same thing goes for the equivalent code in the other two methods... You may as well just remove this dead code.

2) You may want to consider using the `hidden` property of the nodes to show/hide them, rather than actually adding and removing them from the scene. Using this property has the advantage that you can set the `hidden` property to `NO` twice, and the node will just remain hidden. If you call `removeFromParent` twice on a node, your application will crash.

3) To answer your question, one approach is to modify the `doDamage:` method so that it shows/hides the right number of health containers. In order to do that, you'll need a way of referencing the health containers, either by keeping references to them or by using the `name` property. I'd normally do something along these lines:

```
- (void)doDamage:(SKSpriteNode*)character {
    isDamaged = YES;
    hitCount++;
    [self syncHealthContainers];
}

- (void)syncHealthContainers {
    for(int i = 0; i < [healthContainers count]; ++i)
        healthContainers[i].hidden >= (hitCount > ([healthContainers count] - i));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so set up the healthContainers in an array?  I'm still new to all of this, but I am guessing I could make an SKSpriteNode array or some other array in the initWithSize method called at the beginning.  I will attempt that, thanks!

Comment: @stickynugz Look into `NSMutableArray` to hold arrays of Objective-C objects.